# Incompatibilities between modules (spark and jetty) using maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, jetty, apache-spark

I'm creating a program that uses spark and jetty libraries. The dependencies are managed by maven.

The problem is that some Classes are not found if bot dependencies are defined. Specifically `org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector`. There are no problems with other classes. If I remove the spark-core dependency, all work correctly. Why can this happen?

My example is based on this [repository](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples.git) and the error can be reproduced adding the spark-core dependency to the "javax.websocket-example" project

I have tried with different versions of spark-core and jetty- websocket:

- spark-core (2.10 and 2.11): 1.2.0 and 1.2.1
- Javax.websocket-example: 9.3.0.M1, 9.2.7.v20150116 and 9.1.5.v9.1.5.v20140505

Maven dependences:

```
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- Jetty dependency -->
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.7.v20150116</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
```

EDIT:

More information: I have reproduced the error in an empty scenario using vagrant. The box used is [this](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-i386-vagrant-disk1.box). I have installed maven, git and oracle Java using this [manual](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html). I have done the test with "javax.websocket-example" project of this [repository](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples.git).

In this test, the project runs without de spark-core dependency and it doesn't run with the dependence. The version used of the dependency is the last, and I have tried with the project jetty version and with the last of the 9.2.X (9.2.7.v20150116)

DEPENDECIES:

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a dependency problem between the same library with different versions. (spark uses 8.1.XXX and my module uses 9.XX). The dependency cannot be excluded because is used in the modules. Then, this problem is a Java dependency problem and there is not solution without other technologies like OSGi

I Asked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625140/resolving-dependencies-of-incompatible-versions-of-a-library-in-maven)