# Resolving dependencies of incompatible versions of a library in Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have problems with dependencies in Maven-Java. My problem is that two modules have a dependency with different versions and these versions are incompatible. Can I solve it?

A example of the problem

I have three modules (MA, MB and MC) and two libraries (LA and LB), LA has two versions (v1 and v2) and they are incompatible

The first module, MA, contains the main class and It depends on MB and MC

MB module depends on LA v2.

MC module depends on LB version.

LB version depends on LA v1.

Finally, the tree of dependencies is the following:

```
MA
| - MB
|   | - LA (v2) 
| - MC
|   | - LB  
|   |    | LA (v1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if you consider. In Maven exists one thing called **Exclusions**.

Extracted from the documentation:

> Since maven 2.x resolves dependencies transitively, it is possible for
>   unwanted dependencies to be included in your project's classpath.
>   Projects that you depend on may not have declared their set of
>   dependencies correctly, for example. In order to address this special
>   situtation, maven 2.x has incorporated the notion of explicit
>   dependency exclusion. Exclusions are set on a specific dependency in
>   your POM, and are targeted at a specific groupId and artifactId. When
>   you build your project, that artifact will not be added to your
>   project's classpath by way of the dependency in which the exclusion
>   was declared.

Here the link, maybe it could help you to implement the configuration in your pom.xml --> [Maven Exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Comment: I know but it is no a option because both library are necessary. The problem is that if I exclude LA v1 from MA the LB does not work. (A runtime exception (NoClassDefFoundError) happens. If I exclude LA v2 the module MA does not work

Comment: You then have a bigger issue as in traditional environment, both libraries will end up in the same classpath, but with no predifined order and your application will not work anyhow. You better starts looking at OSGi or other frameworks that will allow you to have well isolated classpaths so that the two versions can co-exists at runtime.

Comment: I was afraid that was the problem, now I'm developing my module with the old version of the library

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that OSGi works great for this use case.

Answer (score -1):

This is a Java problem and there is not solution without other technologies like OSGi